# change stl object color on click

Tags: javascript, stl, three.js

I've have a bunch of stl's loaded into a scene.
onclick of a certain id, i would like to change the associated stl's color.

what is happening is that when clicking on one id, all the stls change color
and clicking on any other id all stls will run the else statement.

```
  var menuClick = document.getElementById('menu');
  var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
  var loader2 = new THREE.STLLoader();
  loader.load('models/zBelts.stl', function(zBeltObj) {      //file location
   //create mesh from file and color var
    var zBeltMesh = new THREE.Mesh(zBeltObj, meshBaseColor);
    //rotate mesh
  zBeltMesh.rotateX( -Math.PI / 2 );
  scene.add(zBeltMesh);
  menuClick.addEventListener('click', function() {        //add event listener
    if (event.target.id === 'zbelt') {
      console.log(event.target.id);
               zBeltMesh.material.color.setHex(0xff0000);   //change color of selected object
                zBeltMesh.material.opacity = 1;
                zBeltMesh.material.transparent = true;

        }
    else {
                zBeltMesh.material.color.setHex(0xffffff);  //change color if not selected
                zBeltMesh.material.opacity = .4;
               zBeltMesh.material.transparent = true;

    }
});
});

    //zmotor
    loader.load('models/zMotor.stl', function(zMotorObj) {      //file         location cahnge this line
//create mesh from file and color var
        var zMotorMesh = new THREE.Mesh(zMotorObj, meshBaseColor); ///cahnge this line
                //rotate mesh
      zMotorMesh.rotateX( -Math.PI / 2 );
scene.add(zMotorMesh);    /////////change this line


menuClick.addEventListener('click', function() {        //add event listener
    if (event.target.id === 'zmotor') {
      console.log(event.target.id);
               zMotorMesh.material.color.setHex(0xff0000);   //change color of selected object
                zMotorMesh.material.opacity = 1;
                zMotorMesh.material.transparent = true;

        }
    else {
                zMotorMesh.material.color.setHex(0xffffff);  //change color if not selected
                zMotorMesh.material.opacity = .4;
               zMotorMesh.material.transparent = true;

    }
});
  });
```

Comment: this is in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

All your models share the same material (meshBaseColor), which means when you change zBeltMesh.material.color this changes also zMotorMesh.material.color

Create a "selection material" at the beginning of your code and assign this material to the selected elements in your click event. Be careful to reassign the old material after the selection is canceled / overwritten.